Change CAP_CPU and MAX_CPU
We created a new Elastic Pool and moved some databases in.  Databases in the old Elastic Pool had all databases with CAP_CPU and MAX_CPU as 85.  In the new pool they are 45.  How do I match the old values?

The following instructions work only on Azure Elastic Pools based on vCore Model. On Azure Elastic Pools based on DTU-Model the following instructions have no impact on the max_cpu and cap_cpu values at the database level. On the DTU-model you cannot adjust cores because DTU represents blended measure of cores, IO, log and memory.
You can use Azure Portal, search for the elastic pool, select Configure on the Resource Menu, make a click on Per Database Settings tab, and use the buttons on the slides to configure the min (left button on the slider) and max (right button) as shown on below image:

After adjusting the cores at the pool level also I was able to increase the CAP_CPU and MAX_CPU at the database level.

You can also use a Terraform provider named azurerm_mssql_elasticpool. I found it better, easier to configure an Azure Elastic Pool using Terraform compared with CLI, PowerShell and even the Azure Portal. See min_capacity and max_capacity on below example:
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "my-resource-group"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "my-sql-server"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "4dm1n157r470r"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_elasticpool" "example" {
  name                = "test-epool"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.example.name
  license_type        = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb         = 756

  sku {
    name     = "BasicPool"
    tier     = "Basic"
    family   = "Gen4"
    capacity = 4
  }

  per_database_settings {
    min_capacity = 0.25
    max_capacity = 4
  }
}

The above code extracted from here.

We are using Premium DTU's.  I can adjust the available DTU's to the database, but that don't change the CAP_CPU and MAX_CPU.  When the database is at 100% dtu's the pool is still about 60% utilization.

Could you please edit your original question an add an image or the DMV query that gives you the information about CAP_CPU and MAX_CPU values?

This is my query:
SELECT max_cpu, cap_cpu, * FROM sys.dm_user_db_resource_governance
Databases in our other pools have both 85 for the CPU Numbers.  We are using a Premium elastic Pool

The instructions I provided work only on Azure Elastic Pools based on the vCore model. You cannot adjust values for CAP_CPU and MAX_CPU when using DTU-model Elastic Pools. Remember DTU is a unit of measure representing a blended measure of CPU, memory, reads, and writes. I updated my original answer.
